# Installing postgres on windows with locale

Tags: windows-7, permissions, postgresql, locale

Disclaimer: as this should be a standard operation, i feel something on my side must have gone terribly wrong.

I am trying to use `postgresql` on windows 7<sup>1</sup>. The [installer from edb](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) works fine, apart from an apparently [more than eight years old issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAM2FmMoeykXx2-XqJTtEmTcW9y9MSecbUrdN%2Bjy7vvg_MfdPcg%40mail.gmail.com), where locale names don't match (my gut tells me windows is reporting inconsistent stuff, like it often does). When i select `English, United Kingdom` as locale, it fails, and goes to `English_United States.1252`.

As this is unchangeable after the database cluster creation, i therefore delete it, and attempt to recreate it in the same folder, fixing the locale name problem:

```
initdb --locale="English_United Kingdom" --lc-monetary="English_United States" -E UTF8 -U postgres -W -A scram-sha-256 -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data"
```

Now `initdb` feels like security without an escape hatch is a good thing, drops priviledges it starts with, and then obviously fails to write anywhere in `C:\Program Files`, even when originally started as administrator.

> creating directory C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data ... initdb: error: could not create directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data": Permission denied

How can i reproduce, what the installer would have done, just with the proper locale? I noticed i can create the `data` folder, and grant full permissions to every user, then `initdb` works, but the resulting permissions don't look like what the installer produces at all (e.g. regarding the services user `NETWORK SERVICE`).

---

Edit: the installer executes `getlocales.exe` when started, so injecting a different file is difficult. The `INITDBOPTS` environment variable has lower priority than the installer settings, so it's not useful here.

---

1: yeah windows 7 is EOL i know..., but `postgresql` is like 30 years old, so this really shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why don't you just store the data in a different location that doesn't require permission elevation? Vista was more forgiving when writing data to Program Files, with WIndows 7, you must elevate the permissions of the process itself.  I suspect `initdb` is not being elevated despite being started in an elevated command prompt. I assume you are running a supported version of postgresql? (I could careless you using Windows 7, provided postgresql supports it, or you are running a version of postgresql that supports it).

Comment: As could be sneakily guessed from the folder path, i am trying to install postgres13, the most current that was suggested by the website (i'd even install 14 beta, but there was no installer). Using a different folder may be a solution, but the installer can somehow magically do it in "Program Files" as well. I wanted to stick as close to the defaults as possible, which is "Program Files" (i was actually hoping the installer would work out-of-the-box, but apparently not). Tbh i am generally not bound to postgres, but it seemed like a good choice for my use-case (before it failed at install).

Comment: My current next attempt will be to compile an alternative `getlocales.exe`, which just puts "English_United Kingdom" to stdout, and replace the original mid-install. There appears to be an environment variable `INITDBOPTS`, but the values from the installer supersede it, making it half-useless.

Comment: My experience with Office has taught me to ignore file paths, since every current version of Office, is basically “Office 15”. The thread you linked to talked about a .vbs file and how it should do this function in 9.2; I cannot really think of a way to explain why the installer works the way it does.